# Is There Any Form of Reincarnation in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

It's well known that George Lucas took many of is ideas for the Jedi and the Force (among other things) from elements of Eastern religions.  (I've seen pages, for example, that talk about how much of Star Wars meshes with Buddhist beliefs and other pages that say the same about Hindu beliefs.)  Both of these religions include reincarnation.

Force ghosts show us that there's a sense of a durability of the soul, especially since Qui-Gon went to the Netherworld of the Force, but was still able to come back, which tells us that even in that Netherworld, the soul can maintain integrity.  It's said that eventually Force ghosts have to leave and go to the Netherworld of the Force, too.  Yoda was seen there, training two people.

While the belief is that non-Force sensitives become one with the Force on death (which is like the Buddhist belief of Nirvana), it seems that, in spite of Qui-Gon's beliefs, souls do still have a sense of self in the Netherworld.

Since this establishes the concept of souls continuing to exist after death, is there anything in Star Wars that indicates a soul that has been a Force ghost or has been in the Netherworld of the Force (or elsewhere) has come back in another body?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if this counts as "reincarnation", or whether it can be considered canon, but in one of the optional endings of the videogame [Jedi Knight: Jedi Academy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Jedi_Knight%3a_Jedi_Academy), human Dark Jedi Tavion gets possessed by the ghost of an ancient Sith Lord called Marka Ragnos.

So at least a Force ghost can take over a living body...

Comment: No, this is not the same thing, not even close; and it is also not consistent with the movies or books.

Comment: @scifiaddict Ok... care to explain why? Your comment is not very useful :)

Answer (score 7):

Callista:

> When the automated Imperial dreadnaught Eye of Palpatine came to
>   demolish the settlement, Masana and her lover Geith Eris launched a
>   desperate mission to sabotage the ship. They were successful, but in
>   the process, Masana shed her physical body, remaining embedded in the
>   ship's computer as a spirit. Many years later, Luke Skywalker and
>   several other Jedi were brought onto the ship as it resumed its
>   mission. Masana, in spirit form, communicated and began to fall in
>   love with Skywalker. She later took the body of one of the other Jedi,
>   Cray Mingla, after Mingla gave it up to stop the superweapon once and
>   for all. However, in the process, Masana, now using the surname
>   "Ming," lost her ability to touch the Force.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Callista_Ming

Answer (score 3):

There is the case of Palpatine possessing one of his clones stored on Byss in the Dark Empire series, although I wonder if that could be consider a possession more then a re-incarnation to psychical form.

Comment: Evil, demonic, or spiritual possession is not even remotely close to reincarnation. Even the Christian Bible says that demonic possession is real.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no form of the Hindu religious belief of "reincarnation" incorporated into any of the Star Wars movies or books.

Moreover, the series has a conflicting philosophy, which is that [at least] the Jedi exist in an afterlife and their spirit continues to exist; and further that some of the Jedi who have died or been killed return to help guide Luke Skywalker on his path toward greatness.

Comment: Your answer implies that Hinduism is the only religious belief that includes reincarnation, which is inaccurate.  But then you make a statement about a conflicting philosophy, and present one side, but don't give any indication of where the conflict lies.  This really reads as a poorly thought out answer.  I didn't downvote it, but someone already has and I considered doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Another instance similar to Palpatine's reembodiment by possession of clones, though a bit more like reincarnation, is the case of Bevel Lemelisk, one of the Death Star designers. Lemelisk was executed several times by Palpatine for various failures (including the first Death Star) and then had his essence tranferred by Palpatine to a clone using the Force.

While this is not reincarnation in the typical Eastern religion sense, it's a bit closer than the various instances of possession in Star Wars, because Lemelisk had no control over it.

(Lemelisk's story is in the book *Darksaber*)